# Locate onclick() event location in Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I cant find out how to use on click function

I need the program to make square with in triangles, but only where I click on screen and I can't seem to figure out why it only does it in the center.

```
import turtle
import random
# create a turtle variable



t = turtle.Turtle()
screen = turtle.getscreen()
my_list =  [4,3,2,1]
# function to draw the square pattern
def draw_square_pattern(x,y): 
 for i in my_list:
  t.pencolor("blue")
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(100 * i/4)
  t.left(90)
  t.forward(100 * i/4)
  t.left(90)
  t.forward(100 * i/4)
  t.left(90)
  t.forward(100 * i/4)
  t.left(90)
  t.penup()
  t.forward(12.5)
  t.left(90)
  t.forward(12.5)
  t.right(90)
  t.penup()



# main function

# when click do function
screen.onclick(draw_square_pattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you use x and y in your function, but those coordinates would be important for making the turtle draw at a specific location. Compare the x and y coordinates to the turtle's x and y coordinates, and then use that information to move the turtle to that (x, y) coordinate. Then, continue with your for loop as usual.

Comment: How would I use it in my function?

Answer (score 0):

The turtle event handler is giving you the position where the user clicked as the arguments to your event handler:

```
def draw_square_pattern(x,y):
```

but you're ignoring them.  You can simply raise the pen and go to position (x, y).  Let's rework your code to do that and clean up the syntax a bit:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.pencolor("blue")

my_list = [4, 3, 2, 1]

def draw_square_pattern(x, y):
    """ function to draw the square pattern """

    screen.onclick(None)  # disable handler inside handler!

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)

    for i in my_list:
        turtle.pendown()

        for _ in range(4):
            turtle.forward(100 * i/4)
            turtle.left(90)

        turtle.penup()

        turtle.left(45)
        turtle.forward(17.7)
        turtle.right(45)

    screen.onclick(draw_square_pattern)

screen.onclick(draw_square_pattern)
screen.mainloop()
```

[image]